# Copy a row to another section in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to copy a row to another section when a button in the row is tapped.i have done it.But only the text is getting copied.I also want to move the image which is in that row.

```
-(void)moveRowToAnotherSection:(id)sender{

   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview;
   NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [[self tableView] beginUpdates];

    [tempArr addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.favouritesArray.count inSection:0]];
    [self.favouritesArray insertObject:cell.textLabel.text atIndex:self.favouritesArray.count];
    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)tempArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

   [[self tableView] endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: How have you put the image in tableview cell? Have you made a customised cell?

Comment: Are there images in every cell?

Comment: Well you have not inserted the image in the array of images, from where you must be picking images for cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: yes images are there in every cell

Answer (score 0):

There are three points I want to make:

1) You want to move the image when a particular row is  tapped, right? 
Then why dont you use `Tableview` delegate's method- `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

2) There is a method in `UITableView` that is used to move rows. Here is from the Apple Documentation:

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

> Moves the row at a specified location to a destination location.

Here is the piece of code that moves the tapped row to section 0 row 0.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path toIndexPath:indexPath];
        [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:path];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
```

3) The third point is the main one. `UITableView` by default provides a reordering control and if you want to reorder rows by dragging and not tapping, you can achieve this following these steps:

**Step 1:**

Set your tableview to editing mode. Normally this is done through an Edit Button.

```
[_yourTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

**Step 2:**

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
assign

```
cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
```

**Step 3:**

Implement `UITableViewDataSource`'s method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{
// here you do all the reordering in your dataSource Array. Because dragging rows change the index of your row but the change should reflect in yopur array as well.
}
```

Thats it, you don't need to write any code under beginUpdates and endUpdates block. You just have to implement these three steps.

Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) to learn all about Reordering in `TableView`

Comment: sorry for not being clear in the question.I have a button in every cell.and this has to be done when that button is tapped,and also i dont want to move the whole row i just want to make a copy of it in section 0.